# eclipse JNI_CreateJavaVM error at mac os x

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

i am using mac os x 10.8.2. i have installed java 1.7 and then take back since i can not send iphone applications via xcode. now java 1.6 is installed.

ysnky@ ~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
ysnky@ ~$

but now i can not run eclipse. it does not open, it gives this alert and closed.

The JVM shared library "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

i am really confused and can not find a solution. i just want to run eclipse, that is all :(
thanks.

Comment: Gerry Panganiban solution (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4444438?start=0&tstart=0) works.   damn it  >sudo rm Current
>sudo mv Current.bak Current

Answer (score 4):

> You can download and install from apple website.It works perfect for
>   me

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 2):

Update your Mac. Apple has provided new Java update which fixes this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the file `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current` execute the following command

`cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A Current`

Comment: work with second line as:
sudo ln -nsf /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A Current

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by first removing any previously installed versions of the Oracle Java jdk. Instructions are here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html#uninstall

Then installing Apple's official Java JDK. For some reason the [Java download page on support.apple.com](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) came back blank for me, but via Google's cached copy of the page, I found the direct link to download, which is what finally fixed this issue for me:

http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1572/en_US/JavaForOSX2014-001.dmg

Comment: Note: Apple's download page referred to above is here: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Comment: Hello Jake and welcome to StackOverflow. Note that you can always edit your own answers and in particular add embedded links.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install from apple website.It works perfect for me on mac 10.9.5

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US