# Eclipse won't start after installing Mac OS X Yosemite (Mac OS 10.10)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-yosemite

Right after upgrading to Mac OS Yosemite (10.10), my Eclipse won't start anymore. Instead I get

> The JVM shared library /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib" does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

I checked `java -version` and get

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

I search and have found one similar problem [Reinstalling Java 7 JDK on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806477/reinstalling-java-7-jdk-on-osx). It is suggesting a reinstallation of Java. I am not sure if my problem falls into the same category as his. So, is reinstallation a good way to solve the problem? Any other advice? Thanks!

Comment: Given that Yosemite has only been available for a day I doubt there are many (any?) people with experience of running Eclipse on it yet.

Comment: Can you run other java programs?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the program for ebanking, which uses java, can work. But it is web program.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, you are right. I may be the first one raising this question :) But maybe the thread here can help someone later?

Comment: You have Java 8 installed as a part of Yosemite.  Make sure you're running the latest version of Eclipse.  Earlier versions of Eclipse won't run with Java 8.

Comment: I have Eclipse Kepler (latest version I suppose) and I face same problem. @ileonard were you able to re-instal Java 7 JDK? I read somewhere that people are facing trouble with it as well. (JDK 7 won't install on OSX versions older than v10.7. Perhaps JDK 7 installer thinks that 10.10 < 10.7.)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc My Eclipse Kepler used to work well with JDK 8, but right after I upgrade my OS to Yosemite, it stops working.

Comment: @craftsman Exactly! I tried to install JDK 7 but it told me that JDK 7 won't support OSX older than 10.7! I think Yosemite is so new that it is still bugful?

Comment: I just downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse Kepler and it worked flawlessly. I don't know why previous copy didn't work, but I don't care now.

Comment: @craftsman Cool! Thanks for the info. I will try the same method to see if it works for me.

Comment: @craftsman is right: the installer refuses to install

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Go to the link below and download **Java for OS X 2014-001**

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Hopefully after installing it , it will work

Comment: "This package installs the same version of Java 6 included in Java for OS X 2013-005." But I don't want to downgrade my Java version to run Eclipse. There should be a better way to deal with it.

Comment: My previous java 1.6.0_51 included in Java OSX 2013-05 crush for all java apps. After upgrading to java 1.6.0_65 from JavaForOSX2014-001 everything works well.

Answer (score 24):

Try this https://jdk8.java.net/download.html Java8u20 early Update.

Comment: You should mark this answer as the correct answer if you think this is the right answer.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Also, refer to this entry from Oracle folks: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3595264

Comment: Just to be clear you need to install the JDK and not just the JRE from this page. You also need a current 64 bit (Must be 64 bit) copy of Eclipse (juno) which will look under the 1.7+ location for the JDK /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ rather than the prior 1.6 location of /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

Answer (score 16):

You may change the system version temporarily in the "SystemVersion.plist" located at System > Library > CoreServices.

Edit as root changing ProductVersion to 10.7.3 (or whatever works for you).

Install java.

Don't forget to change it back.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: I changed mine to 10.7.3 - Still got the same message when opening Android Studio

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue creating those empties folders as root without downgrade using java8 (vers.1.8.0_60-ea):

/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk and 
/System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

I installed Java JRE from Oracle: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jre-8u25-macosx-x64.dmg

Then install the Apple Package: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

I was able to install eclipse-ide from homebrew cask

> brew cask install eclipse-ide eclipse-java

(Please be aware that brew cask installs to ~/Applications not /Applications)

I don't normally use Eclipse, however I was able to get the IDE up and going. I will note that java on the command line is broken, which is new in Yosimite.

Please let me know if that doesn't work. Or if you need some help with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [Cask](http://caskroom.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the 64 bit version of Mac Eclipse I just tried it works flawless

Comment: As long as you already have a 1.7+ JDK installed. Older version of Eclipse will not find the new 1.7 location of the JDK which is why some comments you will find online at the time of the 1.7 rollout suggested downgrading to 1.6 in order to make older versions of Eclipse work.

Answer (score 0):

Two cases:

1. if you already have installed Java 8 and Eclipse Luna e.g. on Mavericks and (intent to) update to Yosemite: just update, it will work fine.
2. if you do not have Java installed and want to run Eclipse on Yosemite:

   - install Apple Java 6 files from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572
   - use an Eclipse Version that runs with Java 6, e.g. Kepler from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2

That means, if you want to use Eclipse Luna and Java 8, install it while running Mavericks, then update to Yosemite. Do not try to install Java 8 on Yosemite as that at the moment won't work.

What does not work on my Mac is: installing Java 6 and run Eclipse Luna as that needs Java 7 or 8. Installing Java 7 or 8 does not solve the prob as something with the installer seems to be buggy. Should be solved by Oracle in a few days, however.

Comment: I had Luna and Maverick installed pre update to Yosemite, and no, it doesn't work flawlessly.

Comment: Exactly! Why would he post the question then!? Stuck at the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to yosemite, java 6 jdk is no longer available, remember that jdk 6 for mac osx is a 32-bit application, older eclipse releases needs a 32-bit jvm in order to run properly, a 32-bit application cannot run with a 64-bit jvm like java 7 or 8, so you need to install jdk 6 to run those java applications that needs a 32 bit virtual machine. As already posted here you can download jdk 6 from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US