# Can't run Android Studio on Yosemite

Tags: android, android-studio, osx-yosemite

Can't install Java 7 (installer refuses).

Can install Java 8.

But then starting Android Studio, it says it needs to install the legacy JDK 6, which is not going to work for me because our projects are already 1.7.

Comment: This is a long shot - but for us Eclipse users re-installing the IDE seems to make difference ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023956/eclipse-wont-start-after-installing-mac-os-x-yosemite-mac-os-10-10 . Can't comment more specifically though until I get my share of Yosemite.

Comment: @harism yeah saw that thread before I posted. I ended up installing the legacy 6 AND 8 and AS did install, waiting to see which version it is using for my project and if it runs AS with 6 but allows me to use 8 for the project then my 1.7 syntax issues will be fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We now have an official page describing what to do:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk

Please, please don't edit Info.plist; that has many downsides (including broken patches and application signatures breaking etc). As of Android Studio 1.0 we have a different way of setting the JDK to be used by the IDE.

Comment: This is an issue with IDEA, I've seen the same thing crop up with WebStorm. 
It's crazy that IDEA doesn't consider it important enough to fix after many months. They need to put some effort into it, but don't they seem to want to acknowledge the problem at all, let alone fix it.
Until they do, Android Studio is a non-starter.

Comment: As documented on noted link - at the bottom - setting the STUDIO_JDK environment variable made it work for me on Yosemite.

Answer (score 114):

**UPDATE 2014.12.10**

This should be the final update on this question.

After the final release of Android Studio v1.0, there is an official way to select your JVM, mentioned here:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk

All the following information is kept only as reference, please don't use it.

**UPDATE 2014.11.26**

Editing the `Info.plist` file as suggested in this answer might **break your IDE**.
Please check out the [prescribed solution](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks) mentioned by the IntelliJ folks, and this is the prefered fix to this problem.

If any of the misbehavior/undesired effects mentioned there happen with your setup by using this fix, you should restore the plist file, and use the legacy JDK 6 instead.

If JDK 6 is not an option for your setup, or still have some difficulty to start up the IDE, you can try this fix at your own risk.

Please also **read the comments** under this answer to review feedbacks from other community members(yes, good and bad) and my discussions with them.

**OLDER UPDATE**

This is an outdated answer, when Yosemite is in early Beta stage and could mess your current setup(see the comments, mostly caused by incompatible JVMs when you do need to update/upgrade them).

As mentioned in the original answer, this is a "dirty" fix that time, and the most suitable way to fix this problem now is to **upgrade/update your JVMs as suggested for your OSX system**.

Original answer is put below just for reference, if all the JVM upgrade/update still doesn't work for you, at least you can manually install a JVM and use this hack, but please don't upvote this answer because there are better ones.

==================================

As mentioned as other users, the JDK from Apple and new OSX seems mess things up.

However, there is a dirty quick fix for it.

First, locate your Android Studio, for my machine, it is here:

```
jerry-retina-mbp:Android Studio.app jerry$ pwd
/Applications/Android Studio.app
```

Then find the application bundle description file for it, named "Info.plist":

```
jerry-retina-mbp:Android Studio.app jerry$ ls Contents/Info.plist 
Contents/Info.plist
```

Use "Finder" to open this folder:

```
jerry-retina-mbp:Android Studio.app jerry$ open Contents
```

Then, you can use whatever text editor you like, to modify the JVM settings in "Info.plist"(which is just a XML file).

Before:

```
  <key>JVMVersion</key>
  <string>1.6*</string>
```

After:

```
  <key>JVMVersion</key>
  <string>1.6+</string>
```

Hopefully after this change, your Android Studio will not complain the JVM again.

Comment: This works for Android Studio Beta on Mac OS X Yosemite as well. Thanks!

Comment: It actually works for any JVM. That is just a dummy security hard-coded value. Awesome found. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use `<string>1.6+</string>` with a plus sign instead of the asterisk.

Comment: Following the above instructions caused loads of issues under the final version of Yosemite.  I was getting random android studio crashes, lockups and it messed up my multi-monitor support.

DO NOT EDIT YOUR INFO.PLIST AS THIS ANSWER SUGGESTS.  IT WILL BREAK ANDROID STUDIO.

Instead, I found installing the update here fixed my problems:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Comment: As @LukeSleeman said, it does not seem like this is the best ay to go. Android Studio is based off Intellij, and they are saying to NOT EDIT THE INFO.PLIST file. Instead, they say the soloution is to simply install JAVA JDK 1.6: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks

Comment: Jerry Tian - Please edit your answer!  I see overnight it doubled in upvotes and its at the top of a bunch of relevant google searches.  This indicates that a lot of people are coming here, following the solution and essentially breaking their IDE.  However you don't notice the random crashes until later, so this answer is getting upvoted and spread.

Jerry - Please act quickly!  Due to the Yosemite release this is very timely.  Every hour this answer stays that the top more damage is being done!

Comment: I wouldn't do this. Just click on more on the error dialog and then download the Java for OS X, the link is right there, you don't have to edit anything in your plist.

Comment: Downvoted because it's clear that this is not the correct solution after people reporting it can cause a ton of issues. Please update the answer.

Comment: jerry, if you know your "dirty" fix is going to cause issues for people, you should edit your answer (take out the dirty fix "recipe" altogether) so that people cannot follow it even if they tried.  i actually started out following your instructions because they were the top voted ones by far. adding a simple disclaimer like you did is insufficient. just edit it to *remove your instructions* altogether. (there's NO point in leaving your potentially disastrous instructions in place).

Comment: @Gino As claimed in the latest edit, this dirty fix is the second approach which indeed still help my teammates around here. Surely they tried with the Apple's provided update, some of them are working, but some of them are not. If the latter happened, this last approach always helped, and we have multiple monitor setup too as mentioned by others but without any usage problem.

Comment: @Gino Please also check this official intellij discussion thread on this topic: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks Still some users are complains about usage problems after enabling the update, without editing plist file. And I think the root problem is, why such an old and outdated JVM is required at all. So, as long as the official support doesn't come up(as mentioned in the above thread, a launcher does not require JDK 6), I do think this hack is still helpful.

Comment: The JetBrains guys are ridiculous. Sorry I am not installing 6. I moved the SDK to /usr/local and have just been downloading new versions.

Comment: Please update answer to point to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk -- as of Studio 1.0 we have a different way of setting the IDE JDK than editing Info.plist.

Comment: @Tor You are telling us not to use this method, but it's the only one that seems to work for me, and the same way i had to fix WebStudio.
However, this is a stupid issue that IDEA is not taking seriously and I refuse to use anything based on their products, if I have a choice, until its fixed.

Comment: @Rob I'm with you. Same issue with another product based on their stuff.

Answer (score 41):

If you click "more..." on error dialog it will lead to [Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US). Just download and install it.

Comment: Yeah I did this. As you saw above in the comments I was concerned that installing legacy would not work for me because my codebase requires 1.7 and legacy is 1.6.

Comment: This works for me. In Android Studio requirements they ask for JRE6 and JDK7+ (https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html). They also say that we can configure projects to use JDK7.

Comment: I can't upwote this high enough. You need to install mentioned fix from apple so that Android Studio runs itself using that particular Java version. After that you can install 1.7, 1.8 or whatever you need version and configure your projects to use it. For me this all fixed a bug with dual monitor and AS's floating window constantly jumping back to main monitor. Yay!

Answer (score 13):

I followed the top voted answer, under the final retail version of Yosemite, with android studio 0.8.9 and it caused loads of issues - My multi-monitor setup wouldn't work, and android studio would randomly crash or lock up.

Instead what worked for me was to install the java update at:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

InteliJ do not recommend editing the plist file, to run the IDE under a higher version of java.  It will break the updating system.  In addition there are many bugs which will appear when running under higher versions of java:  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks

Comment: This worked for me as well on the release version of Yosemite. I had already installed Java 7. Installing the legacy Java update from Apple did not disturb the Java 7 setup.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Less risky than the most upvoted answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Java update from Apple worked for me and saved a ton of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I fixed by installing javaforosx. http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US. ;)

Comment: This fixed an issue where a fresh Yosemite machine with only JDK 8 would freeze just after building a larger project.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run

```
java -version
```

If it shows `javac 1.8.*`, then

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.8*</string>
```

otherwise (`javac 1.7.*`), then

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.7*</string>
```

If there is no display at all, you should install Java SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried several solutions, downloading several sdk but Android Studio didn't recognize them as valid sdks.

Finally, the workaround that worked for me was:

1. Delete "Android Studio.app" and Android Studio preferences (~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio).
2. Rename /usr/libexec/java_home to java_home.bak.
3. Install again Android Studio.
4. When Android Studio prompts for a valid Java SDK, follow link provided by Android Studio and download that java installation.
5. After installation, push detect button on Android Studio, and run.

Answer (score 0):

Got this all to work:

- installed the legacy JDK
- installed JDK 8

Found a thread that Oracle is going to update 1.7 so that the installer will not balk at 10.10 but that was not out yet.

This ended up working. Clearly the app itself is using 8 since my language level in my project is set to 1.7 and the legacy JDK is 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was:

1. Open the Info.plist file inside Android Studio.app Folder. (use show package contents context menu)
2. Find the key **JVMVersion** and replace the below version number string with **1.8***.
3. Save

XML Info.plist should look like this

```
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.8*</string>
```

**This Also works on Android Studio 0.9.9**

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Last year I uninstalled Java 6 from Mavericks and installed Java 7, then I install Android Studio and everything was working fine.  I upgraded Android Studio sometime around August or October and I started having the problem everyone is having.  Today, I uninstalled Java 7 and installed Java 8 and added the STUDIO_JDK for Java 8.  I uninstalled Android Studio and installed the latest version of Android Studio.  Now, everything is working like is supposed to.