# Android Studio Release Candidate Refuses to Install on Yosemite

Tags: android, android-studio

To get Android Studio to run on Yosemite, I had to alter the plist, this was covered in this question: [Can't run Android Studio on Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124911/cant-run-android-studio-on-yosemite)

Now there is finally a release candidate for a 1.0! but it refuses to install. Before it would say 'plist was edited, which version do you want?'

Now it just says 'there are problems that cannot be resolved, click cancel.'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do a clean install of 0.8.14 from the developer site, do the upgrade to 1.0 and then modify the plist.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing a fresh install. Couple releases ago, when the update did not work I went back to having the SDK installed off of /usr/local. If you are going to start from scratch, move the SDK first otherwise you will be waiting a long time while everything is downloaded again.

Fresh install was a total breeze.

One other caveat: if you just go looking for Android Studio downloads, you will not find this because it was from the Canary Channel. Those downloads are [here](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary).