# OS X Yosemite - Android Stuio wont start SDK Manager and can't execute gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, osx-yosemite

I’m using MacBookPro OSX YOSEMITE 10.10.3

Till yesterday I was a happy Android Studio user with no complaints. But,
since yesterday Android Studio is making unintelligible trouble.

**1. It’s not possible to start SDK Manager**.

Every time I try to start it from Tools > Android > SDK Manager this happens:

[image]

**2. The next issue comes with Gradle.**

Every time I run my app this pops up:

[image]

My JAVA_HOME is:

```
$JAVA_HOME
-bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home:
```

I’ve reinstalled the Android Studio and JRE, Java SDK and Android SDK several times. Nothing changed. Getting same alerts as you see on the pictures.

I’ve also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28483897/967053) with no success.

Do you have any Idea how to fix this problem!?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install 'Java SE Development Kit 8' to fix this problem. I think it will become normal after that

Comment: Open Terminal and type 'java -version' to determine which version of the JDK is the default

Comment: there is no responde to java -version. Could this be a reason? I've installed JRE 7 ... but no return.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was, that (my) OSX Yosemite doesn't work with Java 8 für Mac OS X from java.com. I've installed the JRE8 many times, but it was still not working. Here is how to solve that problem:

1. Like Tram Nguyen said, Open Terminal and type

   java -version

if there is no responde like

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
```

get Java for OS X 2014-001 from >> [Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=de_DE) !
The Apple version will work on Yosemite.

Try again

```
java -version
```

If there is a responde, well done!

Thanks to Tram Nguyen for helping out.