# Eclipse Installer returns error message on Sierra

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, macos-sierra

Launching the Eclipse mac installer 64 bit (Eclipse Installer.app downloaded from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php?oxygen) on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.3 fails and displays the alert message :

The JVM shared library "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.

My System Preference panel tells me that I have the recommended version of Java (Java 8 update 121).

I tried different things as suggested on different posts (including [Eclipse won't start after installing Mac OS X Yosemite (Mac OS 10.10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023956/eclipse-wont-start-after-installing-mac-os-x-yosemite-mac-os-10-10)) :

- I made sure to use the 64 bits version
- I tried to go back to Java 6 (downloaded from Apple website) but then I get a message telling that I need the latest version of Java (Java 8) to install Eclipse
- I tried older versions of Eclipse (Mars, etc.) but the installer returns  the same alert message
- I tried to re-install Java after editing SystemVersion.plist as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023956/eclipse-wont-start-after-installing-mac-os-x-yosemite-mac-os-10-10) but got the same message.
- I installed Java from the [jdk8 website](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and JDK from the [oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (as suggested by greg-449) but still the same alert message.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by editing the file Contents/Info.plist stored within the Eclipse Installer.app (that you can actually open as a standard folder).

I uncomented this line specifying the vm location

```
<string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
```

**and** I replaced the name of the jdk folder by the one I actually have in my /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines. In my case, `1.8.0.jdk` had to be replaced by `jdk1.8.0_121.jdk`.

Answer (score 2):

Install the Java 8 **JDK** not just the JRE. On macOS the JRE does not provide a complete Java installation.

The current (Java 8 update 121) location for the JDK download is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). You should end up with a `jdk-8u121-macosx-x64.dmg` file to install. Once installed start the `Terminal` app and make sure that `java -version` works.

Comment: Thx greg. I just re-installed the Java 8 JDK from the link you provided. java -version returns `java version "1.8.0_152-ea" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-ea-b01) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b01, mixed mode)`. But still the same alert message from the installer.

Comment: Then I don't know, however Eclipse Oxygen is still under development and may not have been fully tested on macOS. Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2) is the current Eclipse release and runs fine for me on macOS 10.12.3. Or it may be necessary to remove the JRE install.

Answer (score 1):

The following was added in the `whatever.app/Contents/Info.plist`

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
<array>
     <string>-vm</string
      <string>/Users/<yourHomeDir>/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.2-open/bin/java</string>
      <string>-keyring</string>
      <string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
</array>
```

Note that, I experienced this issue while using Eclipse Mat and JDK Mission Control
On Mac OS v11.6 (Big Sur ) ,the dependency was Java 11 .